# Did I lose 15 reputation today? Recalculation didn't do anything

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

Someone unaccepted my answer today, which was accepted Sep 27th. "Unaccept" showed up in my reputation tab. Currently it shows that I obtained 130 reputation today. In /reputation audit, I see I obtained 145 today. I have triggered recalc, and the reputation tab still shows the same thing.

Please clarify, did I lose 15 reputation from **TODAY** or from that day answer was accepted?

I feel it should remove reputation from the day it was accepted, but as I see, it takes 15 from today. Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) ? Shouldn't it take off reputation from Sep 27th & just show the "-15" line today?

http://phpcode.eu/images/1317426024.png

Comment: Good point - from what I remember, it is unclear on whether or not it should stay grouped with its original entry, or be created as a new entry on a new day.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: I'd like to keep -15 as is, but remove reputation from day answer was accepted, not from day it was unaccepted

Comment: The challenge is dealing with answers that are unaccepted months later.  The way it is right now makes it easier to track the day-to-day changes in your reputation.  Even though someone unaccepting your answer reduces your reputation value for Sep 27th, you had that reputation until today.

Comment: Reputation recalcs don't affect the reputation tab in any way. It'll just change your site rep.

Comment: @NullUserException_: it should. It did for me a lot times

Comment: @NullUserException_: thanks for grammar edits :( I'm still learning and trying to do my best

Comment: Hmmm that's interesting. They don't change anything for me. My [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception?tab=reputation) says I got 289 points for yesterday, even though my `/reputation` audit tells me I've got 290. And I just performed a recalc.

Comment: @NullUserException_: I see [290](http://phpcode.eu/images/1317459587.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is by-design, the -15 shows *on the day it occured*, which is correct as your rep *that day* did change by a net -15 as a result of the unaccept happening *that day*.  This is for a convenient view of "what changed in my rep today?" which is a question/email we get *a lot*.

The reputation report has a different view, the accept being deleted means it *never happened*, we haven't changed this behavior.

There is a long-term plan to have a better representation of all of this, but it requires quite a bit of work on the back-end for a denormalized log-type linear event storage, rather than a interpretation of historical vote data which happens currently.  But...that chunk of time hasn't been available yet, we'll get to it when possible.

Comment: "The reputation report has a different view, the accept being deleted means it never happened" - it means I should lost 15 reputation from day it was accepted. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @genesis-φ - Nope, your rep went *up* 15 **on that day**, and when it was unaccepted you lost 15 rep **on *that* day**, from the `/reputation` report though we just exclude it entirely like it never happened, since the goal there is representing you an accurate total.