# Wrong display of reputation changes (unaccepts again)

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did I lose 15 reputation today? Recalculation didn't do anything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108021/did-i-lose-15-reputation-today-recalculation-didnt-do-anything)

This question is marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [When someone unaccepts your answer after initially accepting it, it looks like the net change is -15, but it's actually 0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107027/when-someone-unaccepts-your-answer-after-initially-accepting-it-it-looks-like-th). Yet the [reputation display in my IT Security account](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/4778/wladimir-palant?tab=reputation) is still wrong: There is a -15 reputation change from the unaccept but no corresponding +15 change from the preceding accept. If you add up all the reputation changes you get 33 instead of 48 which would be the correct value.

Is the display only correct if accept and unaccept happen on the same day or is there some other issue?

Comment: @UphillLuge: I don't think that they are the same. I don't question the -15 reputation change, it is clearly correct. My concern is that the reputation changes don't add up correctly because the original accept is missing from the list.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I had to roll back most of your edit. Given that "accept" and "unaccept" are the terms used on the reputation page you made my question harder to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in [the most recent reputation refactor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), these cases will now be displayed appropriately as the system is rolled out across the network.