# What do the reputation values for unaccept and accept mean?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

How do unaccept and accept work? I see different reputation values:

[image]

Why do they differ?

Comment: Uhuh, duplicate of [older answer by the same author](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes/124192#124192). Please don't do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP can change the accepted answer at any time. If he accepts your answer you gain 15 reputation points ("accept"), if he reconsiders after that you lose 15 points ("unaccept"). If the OP is indecisive and changes the accepted answer several times you get a high "accept" score but also a similarly high "unaccept" score (equal if your answer ended up not accepted or 15 lower if it was accepted in the end). In your screenshot the sequence for the first answer was:

```
accept -> unaccept -> accept
  +15       -15         +15
```

And even more fun for the second answer:

```
accept -> unaccept -> accept -> unaccept -> accept
  +15       -15         +15       -15         +15
```

In both cases your answer was accepted in the end and you ended up with a +15 net reputation change.

Comment: so why it can't be -15 and +15 if I anyway got +15 rep?

Comment: @Vytautas: Because each step was a reputation change. And SO now makes sure to [show each reputation change correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes). Previously it tried to "sum up" the changes which caused issues like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108476/wrong-display-of-reputation-changes-unaccepts-again).

Comment: But then, @Wladimir, why doesn't it show "3 events" and "5 events", like [elsewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes/124207#124207)? We've even [seen "22 events"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zuYZR.png).

Comment: @Arjan: Actually, that's what I see when I look at Vytautas' profile. No idea why he himself sees "aggregated" values.

Comment: @Wladimir, see Nick's comment [at the duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes/124192#124192).

Comment: Though I see it just like the OP does, [for February 27th and 21st here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/486349/vytautas?tab=reputation&sort=time).

Comment: @Arjan: Now I understand. The events are only "aggregated" if you sort by time, not when you sort by post however.