# Confusing reputation count

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, reputation-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What do the reputation values for unaccept and accept mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124202/what-do-the-reputation-values-for-unaccept-and-accept-mean)

My answer got selected  for the question [Change speed of HTML Title tag showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550171/change-speed-of-html-title-tag-showing-up/12550194#12550194) and for that i should have got the +15 reputation but it still showing the 0.

[image]

and its one hour ago so i dont think it in the queue. so is it bug in reputation ?? or anything else ?

Comment: What's confusing about it? Your answer was unaccepted and immediately reaccepted. `-15 + 15 = 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what you show there, the answer was *unaccepted* first, subtracting 15 points, then it was reaccepted, adding those 15 back; leaving a balance of 0 for those actions. You don't show it, but presumably the OP had accepted it before, perhaps 'yesterday' (in UTC); you would have gotten the +15 then.

Answer (score 4):

The OP had originally accepted your answer at 04:23:04 on Sep 24. He then unaccepted your answer at 01:46:28 today, then accepted your answer again at 01:46:29 today. He probably just accidentally clicked it and clicked it again immediately after realizing what he had done. Or he may not be familiar with the accept feature.