# Showing unaccepts for answers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, accepted-answer, reputation-history

I noticied this question: [Notification when my answer is unaccepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted) and [Wrong display of reputation changes (unaccepts again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108476/wrong-display-of-reputation-changes-unaccepts-again) but saying this was fixed and that this feature was in the main Q&A platform however I have just received an unaccept which just said -15 rep but didn't give me any reason on my timeline.

It wasn't until I actually asked a question about hidden rep changes and checked my rep 5 times over that I realised it was due to an unaccept.

Any chance this feature might be broken? (hence why I've marked this as a bug)

Edit:

I have just found out this is because I got the accept and unaccept in the same day which isn't actually a bug. Maybe it might be a feature request to show unaccepts as well as accepts despite being of the same day?

Comment: Unaccepts within the same day they were accepted don't show up in the rep history.

Comment: @Mysticial Ah that I didn't know thanks :)

Comment: @Mysticial Maybe it should? Cos it was kinda confusing to me, or would this be a bad thing do you reckon?

Answer (score 8):

Votes and accepts that are undone within the same UTC day are coalesced and will not show up in the rep history.

When the [new rep system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes) was implemented, every single action was shown - including all the "bouncing" votes. [So they were later all merged together.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/new-reputation-is-too-verbose-upvote-unupvote-upvote-again)

Comment: Confirming this is correct.